# Unhandled exception in try catch all

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Why does the catch-all not handle this exception when input is zero?

```
try
{
    int input;
    std::cin >> input;
    // input is zero
    int x = 50 / input;
    cout << "you will never see this if input is zero";

}
catch (...)
{
    cout << "or this for some reason";
}
```

EDIT: I'm not trying to handle a divide by zero scenario, just wondering why catch all didn't work for that particular case. Thanks dude.

Comment: There is no exception in your code. (Your code has a bug.)

Comment: Because it's a CPU exception, which is different from a C++ exception and can't be caught with `catch`. You need a better way to validate input (especially considering that C++ exceptions are expensive if thrown, and should only be used for truly *exceptional* events).

Comment: Note in the duplicate there is an answer showing how to convert a CPU error to a C++ exception using lambdas and a shared_ptr. The answer shows both gcc and Windows solutions.